# coldfusion session variable disappearing

Tags: session, coldfusion

I have a variable, session.acclevel, which is set during the login process (the program is login2.cfm).

```
<cfset session.acclevel = logdata['LOGACCESS'][1]>
```

The values can be N,R,W,A,M, and they are retrieved with query name = "logdata" from a table which I'm calling XXX here. If the login is successful, login2.cfm redirects to program navbar.cfm

```
<cflocation url = "navbar.cfm?welc=yes">
```

which is a set of dropdown menus, rather like a dashboard.  Depending on the value of `session.acclevel navbar` shows more or fewer options.  The `session.acclevel` variable is also used throughout the system to control various user activities.

All this was working fine, and then it suddenly stopped working -- `session.acclevel was fine when navbar started up, but disappeared as soon as any selection was made.  Yet, no code had been changed.  The only thing I had changed was to alter the MySql table definition of the` acclevel` variable type:

```
alter table XXX change LogAccess LogAccess enum('A','W','R','N','M');
```

to add the option 'M' to the enum.  I did not chnage any data in that table, and I made no changes to the coding anywhere.

I double checked the timeouts (I am using system admin defaults), and tried without success to trace where the variable was getting lost.  I closed and reopened the browser, without fixing anything.

Finally I went to the administrator and changed session management to J2EE -- and that fixed it. `session.acclevel` is now staying put.

Could someone explain what was going wrong there? I would like to know in case this defect in the ColdFusion session management is caused by weak code that I could avoid, or in case it later breaks under J2EE management.

Comment: Can you supply your `application.cfc` settings for session management?

Comment: Make sure `this.setClientCookies` is set to `true` in your `Application.cfc` (or `<cfapplication setClientCookies="true">`, if you use `Application.cfm`). Otherwise you have to provide CFID and CFTOKEN yourself with every request. This applies to the CF session management only.

Comment: Alex, that is no doubt the problem, because I didn't have it set that way.  Since I've changed to J2EE, is it worthwhile going back and setting it anyway?

Comment: James, I've got: <cfapplication name = "Moxware" sessionmanagement = "Yes"> -- it's in  Application.cfm.

Comment: This query you mention, does it return any results when run from ColdFusion?  If not, what about when you run it outside ColdFusion?

Comment: The query returns the correct results.  The session.acclevel variable is initially set correctly based on those results.  It gets lost somewhere later in the process.